# Book about farmer and animal that eats too much

Tags: identification-request

I need help identifying a children’s book I had back in the late 80’s/early 90’s. It was about a farmer who had a goat (maybe a dog) and he bought a bag of food. The goat/animal at all the food and became sick and bloated. The animal just couldn’t help himself. The goat ended up learning a lesson. This is not the Greedy Goat or Gregory the terrible eater. I remember the book having more claymation type of photos.

Answer (score 4):

*Sunny the Greedy Goat Learns the Value of Self-Control* by Ethel Barrett looks like possibility:

> A greedy little goat learns to control himself after suffering the ill effects of an eating binge.

The above summary is quoted from [the book's entry at WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/sunny-the-greedy-goat-learns-the-value-of-self-control/oclc/20169350).

There are few images available Chinese website [258sd.com](http://www.258sd.com/goods/266896.html).

Comment: Yes! This is the exact book I’ve been looking for, thank you!!

Comment: @Jessica You seem to have created a new account, different from the "Jessica B" account that posted the question. Please can you [merge your accounts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)? Then you will be able to click the checkmark and make this answer "accepted", which marks the question as solved and gives a little extra thank-you reputation to the answerer.